# Rendering CSS file from String variable.

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to render a css file from a string data that i found from my controller class?
I have a jsp page, and the page will try to get a css varilable like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style/css=${css}" />
```

Style is the method on the controller class that returns css string variable. Simply the Style method returns a string. I have it on jsp. But i couldn't render it as a css file, it just returns it on the page. Is there any way to render that string as a css file.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't do that. Easiet solution:

```
<style type="text/css"> ${css} </style>
```

Otherwise you have to create new file with contents of `${css}` variable and than include it in html with `<link>` tag.